# How to add span element to json data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

I have a problem with JSON data. I want to add a span element inside a string, but it doesn't work. How to ''escape'' string? Below is an example.

```
{
    "text": "Copyright©2020 <span class="test">Gamepix</span> All Rights Reserved."
}
```

Comment: escape quotes: `\"test\"`, or `'test'`

Comment: Thanks @syduki, but I still have the same problem: https://prnt.sc/10ttv6r, but I want to apply this class styling to the span element.

Comment: @JovanaMarčeta what does that screenshot have to do with JSON?

Comment: this should be something specific to your app, handlebars maybe...

Comment: I resolve this bug...I needed to use triple curly braces in code {{{ftext}}} instead of two, and now it works. Thank you guys anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Typescript you can use in your HTML file [innerHTML].
Example:

```
<div [innerHTML]="text"></div>
```

in your typescript file:

```
text: string = "some text here <span class='yellow'>six pieces</span>, and here";
```

and in your .scss file:

```
::ng-deep .yellow {
    color: #f5dc27;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to this question but I just worked this out for myself! The "render" function takes my data in the JSON key "data" and returns the data in "dataname" as well as my desired html tag (span). 
 Hope this helps!

```
            {
               "data": "dataname", render: function (data) {
                    return data + '<span></span>';
                }  
            },
            "Other data keys to follow" 
            {
            },
```